# C++ Inheritance error: Why is the function in the derived class not overloaded?

Tags: c++, oop

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

class Animal{
    protected: 
        void eat(const string animal){cout << animal << " can eat" << endl;}
        void sleep(const string animal){cout << animal << " can sleep" << endl;}
};

class Dog: protected Animal{
    private: 
        string aniName = "Dog";
    public:
        void eat(){eat(aniName);}
        void sleep(){sleep(aniName);}
        void bark(){cout << aniName << " can bark" << endl;}
};
```

In this code, why isn't the eat function in class Dog(derived class) accessing the eat function in class Animal(base class)? Why is the function in the derived class not being overloaded?

The eat function in the derived class should be overloaded.
The compiler shows error describing too many arguments in function call.

Comment: please include the error message in the question.

Comment: It isn’t being overloaded because there is no other definition in the same scope. It is *hiding* the base class definition.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 4):

This is how namelookup works. `eat` is found in `Dog`, namelookup stops there, and `Dog::eat` cannot be called with one argument.

You can bring `Animal::eat` into scope of `Dog` via `using Animal::eat`:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

class Animal{
    protected: 
        void eat(const string animal){cout << animal << " can eat" << endl;}
};

class Dog: protected Animal{
    private: 
        string aniName = "Dog";
    public:
        using Animal::eat;
        void eat(){eat(aniName);}
};
```

For details I refer you to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup. It has an example with method in a derived class shadowing one from the base, like in your code (you find it if you search for `struct B1: virtual X`).

Answer (score 1):

When you are in the Dog class and you are using the method named "eat," if you want to trigger the method from your superclass (in our case, Animal), you need to explicitly specify that. There are a few ways to do this, as someone mentioned above with "using Animal::eat;." Another approach is to use the name of your superclass and invoke the method like this:

```
void eat() { this->Animal::eat(aniName); }
```

Without using the explicit name of the superclass, the compiler assumes that you are referring to the method of the current class, "Dog."